# obtener la suma automaicamente de dos campos en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

espero me puedan ayudar con este inconveniente, tengo una tabla llamada "total" donde tengo lo siguiente:

```
    id  num1  num2  num3  suma
     1     0    0     0      0
```

lo que necesito es crear un trigger que cuando inserte un valor en los campos "num", se vaya realizando la suma en el campo "suma". he intentado el siguiente código pero me da error, intente con un WHERE pero no se como obtener el id de donde se genero el evento. Estoy trabajando en mySql, o si hay otra forma de hacerlo se los agradezco mucho.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER SUMANDO_AU AFTER UPDATE ON total FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    UPDATE total SET suma=num1+num2+num3

    END
```

Comment: por qué hacer esto con un trigger?, es mucho mejor tener una "columna generada" en mysql

Comment: Lamak porque es un dato que se ingresara mensual.

Comment: pero eso no hace diferencia. La columna generada automáticamente va a mostrar el cálculo que quieres, sin necesidad de hacer un trigger aparte

Comment: @Lamak Lo que pasas es que quiero que se vea la información desde un programa que estoy haciendo, fácilmente podría hacerlo con la lógica del programa y no habría problema, pero si llegado el caso quisiera ingresar una cuota desde la misma base de datos tendría que ponerme a generar la consulta y lo que deseo es que siempre este ese campo presente en la tabla, si existe la manera de hacerlo con el trigger, me gustaría saber como se hace.

Comment: pero buscaste lo que es una columna generada?, justamente es una columna que queda en la tabla de forma virtual o guardada, que contiene el cálculo que quieres y que por lo tanto siempre está disponible

Comment: @Lamak no encontré sobre eso, solo columnas calculadas, si usted me da un ejemplo se lo agradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciertamente nada te impide trabajar con un `trigger` para actualizar una columna:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SUMANDO_AU BEFORE UPDATE ON total FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.suma2=ifnull(NEW.num1, 0) + ifnull(NEW.num2, 0) + ifnull(NEW.num3, 0);
END;
```

Comentarios:

- No existe una sentencia de  `update` en la misma tabla ya que generaría un loop con el mismo trigger
- Por lo anterior, si hay que actualizar la propia tabla hay que usar el `BEFORE UPDTAE` y trabajar con la pseudo tabla `NEW` que representa las nuevas filas y columnas.

- El `ifnull()` nos evita problemas con eventuales valores `NULL`

Ahora bien, tal como opina Lamak, si la necesidad es solo la de llevar una columna totalizadora, y trabajas con la versión 5.7 o superior, es mucho más óptimo trabajar con una [columna calculada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). Estas columnas pueden o no existir físicamente.

```
CREATE TABLE total(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    num1  INT,
    num2  INT,
    num3  INT,
    suma INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(num1, 0) + ifnull(num2, 0) + ifnull(num3, 0))
);
```

Comentarios:

- El "default" de estas columnas es `VIRTUAL` o sea no persistentes, `STORED` es lo contrario
- Necesitarás una columna "persistente" en caso que desees usarla en algún índice.
- Si la columna es persistente, los datos se actualizan con cada `insert` o `update` de forma automática, en caso contrario el valor se recalcula en cada consulta que se haga.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar señor @Patricio, la opción de la columna calculada me funciono, el primer código del trigger me da error, de igual manera con la columna calculada me servirá por el momento. Aunque no deja de ser frustrante no poder entender el código, me la he pasado todo el día leyendo la documentación de sql y aun no logro entender, pero bueno, será seguir estudiando.

Comment: Te dejo, por si te sirve, una prueba de concepto de los dos métodos: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9596fe8e6b9bbccb1844dc3dfdb5040c

Comment: Buen día, al ingresar la instrucción sql me daba error, pero al ingresar la misma instrucción por medio de la herramienta que ofrece phpMyAdmin funciona perfectamente el trigger, gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder